# Is it allowed to use #1step as a procedural delay?

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am not sure if the LRM is clear about the #1step usage, but I have a case of creating a smallest possible delay a simulator could detect. So, I have written the following code:

```
virtual task drive_signal();
      // Initialise mysignal to a value of '1'.
      m_vif.mysignal= 1;
      #1step; // Advance with 1 time step
      m_vif.mysignal= 0;
      #m_cfg.configured_delay; //Delay by configured value
      m_vif.mysignal= 1;

endtask
```

Is this a valid way to do so?
I did however use `#0` instead of `#1step` but it did not create any runtime delay.

Comment: I think LRM is clear about #1step and it is intended for clocking blocks for specific cases. As such, your use, if compilable, is implementation dependent. Delays in simulation have nothing to do with scheduling regions, unless you think about glitches and races, so neither #1step nor #0 are good for it. The smallest delay is something like `#1` (depending on your timescale setting).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is currently an [open issue](https://accellera.mantishub.io/view.php?id=5705) in the [IEEE 1800-2017 SystemVerilog LRM](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/8299595), but the intent was not to allow it.

The use of simple delays like #0 or #1 is a bad practice as they increase the potential for race conditions. Since you tagged this question with UVM, the use of *any* delays in a driver is highly discouraged and instead you should use synchronous clock edge in an interface or top-level testbench.